# zend select from two tables 3 sets of rows

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, zend-db, multi-select

I have this problem using Zend and I think its db related at all:

I have two tables, one contains:

```
id, ..., file, desc, date
```

and the second table contains:

```
id, ..., file_1, desc_1, file_2, desc_2, date
```

What I need as a result is:

```
id, ..., file, desc, date
```

From both tables, which means I need to have coresponding file, desc and file_1 ->file, desc_1->desc and file_2->file, desc_2->desc in this one table.

Any idea how to do this with Zend 1.12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JOIN in Zend ORM

for exmaple

public function getPendingProjects($owner){

```
$data = $this   ->getAdapter()
                ->select()
                ->from('campaign' , array('title', 'id'))
                ->joinLeft('job', 'campaign.id = job.campaign_id', array('count(user_id)'))
                ->where('campaign.employer_id = ' . (int)$owner . ' AND job.status = 3' );

return $data->query()->fetchAll();
```

}

taked from here http://zend-frameworks.com/en/articles/zend_db_zend_mysql.html